# How to replace &nbsp; to space?

Tags: c#, regex

Content is

```
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Hello World.

<a&nbsp;href="#"&nbsp;target=_blank>hello&nbsp;World</a>
```

How to replace the `&nbsp;` in html code and keep the other `&nbsp;` in the text.

Comment: If possible, you should try to avoid getting the `&nbsp;` into your html code in the first place.

Comment: Yes, how did you get in this situation anyway? Show us that code.

Comment: What program are you using to create that markup?

Comment: look at this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705996/mysql-replace-spaces

I execute content = content.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try searching for

```
(?<=<[^>]*)&nbsp;
```

and replacing it with a single space?

This looks for `&nbsp;` inside tags (preceded by a `<` and possibly other characters except `>`).

This is extremely brittle, though. For example, it will fail if you have `<`/`>` symbols in strings/attributes. Better avoid getting those  `&nbsp;` into the wrong locations in the first place.

Comment: RegEx for simple replace? This looks like trying to shot a single fly with nuclear bomb :)

Comment: @Andrey: It's not a simple replace. You might want to read the last line of the question again. ;-)

Answer (score 20):

For me the best is :

```
Imports System.Web
HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(codeHtml)
```

Comment: When leaving an answer, it is important to try to do 2 things.... make sure your answer addresses the question as asked, and explain why your solution addresses the problem.  This is important because not everyone who reads this question will be an expert and will not be able to see how your solution solves the problem.  Consider editing your answer to try to explain how it solves the problem.

Comment: This is actually the best answer here, although poorly explained. See MSDN documentation for what HtmlDecode actually does.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question completely. It converts `&nbsp;` to a non-breaking space (good) that is not equivalent to a normal space in string comparisons (what the question originally asked?)

Answer (score 5):

It's simple

```
youString.Replace("&nbsp;", " ");
```

String class
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx

Replace method
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx

Comment: agree, in this case he should use regex.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 3):

```
string A = HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlDecode(Text);

string A = Text.Replace("&nbsp"," ");

string A = Text.Replace("&amp;nbsp;", " ");

                           ↑ &amp;nbsp;
```

Answer (score 1):

This will find you all those strips of the text containing &nbsp:

```
<[^>]+?&nbsp;[^<]+?>
```

Fropm here you can just do a simple string replaces with the space since Regex will give you the lcoation ofthe match in your text.

Answer (score 1):

just Replace &nbsp to string.Empty after Text  Like Below..

> `xyz.Text.Replace("&nbsp;", string.Empty);`

Answer (score -2):

//Funciona!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

string a =UnHtml(text);

//---------------------------------------------------

```
 private static readonly Regex _tags_ = new Regex(@"<[^>]+?>", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Compiled);

    //add characters that are should not be removed to this regex
    private static readonly Regex _notOkCharacter_ = new Regex(@"[^\w;&#@.:/\\?=|%!() -]", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    public static String UnHtml(String html)
    {
        html = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(html);
        html = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(html);

        html = RemoveTag(html, "<!--", "-->");
        html = RemoveTag(html, "<script", "</script>");
        html = RemoveTag(html, "<style", "</style>");

        //replace matches of these regexes with space
        html = _tags_.Replace(html, " ");
        html = _notOkCharacter_.Replace(html, " ");
        html = SingleSpacedTrim(html);

        return html;
    }

    private static String RemoveTag(String html, String startTag, String endTag)
    {
        Boolean bAgain;
        do
        {
            bAgain = false;
            Int32 startTagPos = html.IndexOf(startTag, 0, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
            if (startTagPos < 0)
                continue;
            Int32 endTagPos = html.IndexOf(endTag, startTagPos + 1, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
            if (endTagPos <= startTagPos)
                continue;
            html = html.Remove(startTagPos, endTagPos - startTagPos + endTag.Length);
            bAgain = true;
        } while (bAgain);
        return html;
    }

    private static String SingleSpacedTrim(String inString)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Boolean inBlanks = false;
        foreach (Char c in inString)
        {
            switch (c)
            {
                case '\r':
                case '\n':
                case '\t':
                case ' ':
                    if (!inBlanks)
                    {
                        inBlanks = true;
                        sb.Append(' ');
                    }   
                    continue;
                default:
                    inBlanks = false;
                    sb.Append(c);
                    break;
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString().Trim();
    }
```

https://newbedev.com/remove-html-tags-from-string-including-nbsp-in-c