# Split paragraph from html string and remove empty paragraph

Tags: c#, html, regex

I have a string of html. I want to split all paragraph into an array list. But the splitted paragraph should be not empty. The splitted paragraph should contain some normal text, if it contain only html text and inside it there is no normal text like: `<htmltag>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</htmltag>`, then it should be destroy or not splitted.

This is an example of how to split paragraph inside html string:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match m = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(htmlString, @"<p>\s*(.+?)\s*</p>");
ArrayList groupCollection = new ArrayList();
while (m.Success)
{
   groupCollection.Add(m.Value);
   m = m.NextMatch();
}
ArrayList paragraphs = new ArrayList();
if (groupCollection.Count > 0)
{
   foreach (object item in groupCollection)
   {
      paragraphs.Add(item);
   }
}
```

The code above can split all paragraph but it cannot recognize which paragraph is empty like I said above.

Comment: What you have tried.?

Comment: I have tried RegularExpressions to split all paragraph from the html string. But then I'm not sure it is empty.

Comment: Can you post your code with question..?

Comment: If I use RegularExpressions, then it only help me to split the paragraph, but if there is some text like: `<htmltag>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</htmltag>` then I don't know how to remove these empty html tags.

Comment: When you split the string and store it in the array variable that time before storing it check that the value contain space `" "` like this. Might this will help you.

Comment: if the "space" here is an html language, then how can I recogize it? Like an example: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

Comment: If user input an html tag like this: `<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>`. Then it is still a paragraph even in html page it view nothing.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708734/how-to-replace-nbsp-to-space] This might help you. It some what same as your question...

Answer (score 0):

I have answer for my own question. This is the code on my own edition:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match m = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(htmlString, @"<p>\s*(.+?)\s*</p>");
    ArrayList groupCollection = new ArrayList();
    while (m.Success)
    {
        groupCollection.Add(m.Value);
        m = m.NextMatch();
    }
    ArrayList paragraphs = new ArrayList();
    if (groupCollection.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (object item in groupCollection)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex rx = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("<[^>]*>");
                // replace all matches with empty string
                string str = rx.Replace(item.ToString(), "");
                string str1 = str.Replace("&nbsp;", "");
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(str1))
                {
                    paragraphs.Add(item.ToString());
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                //This try-catch just prevent future error.
            }
        }
    }
```

On the code above. You can see that I am remove all html tag in the paragraph first, then replace all empty in html string. This will help me to identify an empty paragraph.