# Replacing &nbsp; space character from web page in code behind

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, vb.net

I have some problems replacing a blank space in a webform control label.

Here is my label:

```
<label id="Lbl1" runat="server">TEXTA&nbsp;&nbsp;TEXTB</label>
```

Here is what I would like to do:

```
Dim s As String = Lbl1.InnerText.Replace(" ", "/") 'vb
String s = Lbl1.InnerText.Replace(' ', '/'); //c#
```

But the `&nbsp;` web page special char is not recognized as a blank space by C# / vb.net.

The string received in code behind looks like "TEXTA TEXTB", the `&nbsp;` string doesn't appear. It looks like a space char but isn't.

Is there a way to replace it?

Comment: couldn't you just do a replace on '&nbsp;'?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708734/how-to-replace-nbsp-to-space

Comment: Sorry my question wasn't clear enough I'll edit it. The string received in code behind looks like "TEXTA TEXTB", the "&nbsp;" string doesn't appear. It's looks like a space char but isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

**Lbl1.InnerText** replace with **Lbl1.InnerHtml**

```
String s = Lbl1.InnerHtml.Replace("&nbsp;&nbsp;", "/"); //c#
```