# How to change &nbsp; to space

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a **simple rich text editor** by using contenteditable div.
Now, I what I want is to change the `&nbsp;` to a space.

I found this similar question [How to replace &nbsp; to space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708734/how-to-replace-nbsp-to-space) in which the solution is to use **REGEX** but the answer doesn't provide any sample code and I really don't know how to use that.

I have this javascript code here:

```
if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    document.execCommand('inserText', false, ' ');
    return false;
}
```

In which as the user presses <kbd>space</kbd>, a space would insert as a text but by retrieving it, it's value is `&nbsp;`

Comment: Well, ``&nbsp;`` is a space character. What exactly are you planing to do? Where does your input come from, where do you want it to go and how is it processed (server site or client site)?

Comment: @user1438038 Yes, i just wanted to replace the &nbsp with space. Like this (you`&nbsp;`and`&nbsp;`me) would just be (you and me).

Comment: What is wrong with `&nbsp;` - why is this a problem?

Comment: @Archer It's because i wanted to save in my database this text `you and me` instead of saving it by `you&nbsp;and&nbsp;me`

Comment: Okay, then replace it at server-side before you save it, rather than breaking it in the browser.  If you have five spaces (for example) then they will be trimmed to one.  If you have `&nbsp;` 5 times then it is not trimmed.  Leave it as it is in the browser, as it's like that for a reason.

Comment: You've got a point with that @Archer, thanks! I'll just do it with the backend.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the JavaScript `replace` function using Regex with the global flag:

```
str.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ');
```