# Show whitespace instead of &nbsp; after HTMLEncode

Tags: asp-classic, html-encode

Looking at an old ASP file, I am trying to figure out what would the best practice be in achieving the following:
I am receiving a `string` through a database connection.
This string is the displayed part of a select box.
I am required to output this string using `Server.HTMLEncode(string)`.
However, since there are spaces in that string I get the output as `&nbsp;`.

What would the best practice be in converting back `&nbsp;` into actual whitespace?

Comment: You can use replace("&nbsp;"," ")

Comment: It should works

Comment: Unfortunately this gives me a runtime error '800a01a8'.

Comment: See this URL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708734/how-to-replace-nbsp-to-space, may Replace("&amp;nbsp;"," ")

Comment: I got the error due to using classic asp - not asp.net ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace `&nbsp;` with whitespace in classic ASP I used the following code:

```
<%= Replace(Server.HTMLEncode(string),"&nbsp;"," ") %>
```

Where `string` is the variable that contains `&nbsp;`.